# What is the difference between :id, id: and id in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, mutation

I am trying to build a ruby on rails and graphQL app, and am working on a user update mutation. I have spent a long time trying to figure it out, and when I accidentally made a typo, it suddenly worked.

The below is the working migration:

```rb
module Mutations
  class UpdateUser < BaseMutation
    argument :id, Int
    argument :first_name, String
    argument :last_name, String
    argument :username, String
    argument :email, String
    argument :password, String

    field :user, Types::User
    field :errors, [String], null: false

    def resolve(id:, first_name:, last_name:, username:, email:, password:)
      user = User.find(id)
      user.update(first_name:, last_name:, username:, email:, password:)
      { user:, errors: [] }
    rescue StandardError => e
      { user: nil, errors: [e.message] }
    end
  end
end
```

The thing I am confused about is when I define the arguments, they are colon first: eg `:id` or `:first_name`

When I pass them to the resolve method they only work if they have the colon after: eg `id:` or `first_name:`

When I pass the variables to the update method, they use the  same syntax of colon after, for all variables other than ID. For some reason, when I used `id:` it was resolving to a string "id", and using colon first `:id` was returning an undefined error.

It is only when I accidentally deleted the colon, and tried `id` that it actually resolved to the passed through value.

My question for this, is why and how this is behaving this way? I have tried finding the answer in the docs, and reading other posts, but have been unable to find an answer.

Please someone help my brain get around this, coming from a PHP background, ruby is melting my brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to take some time to get used to Ruby, coming from PHP, but it won't be too bad.

Essentially `id` is a variable, or object/model attribute when used like `model_instance.id`. In PHP this would be like `$id` or `$object_instance->id`.

When you see `id:` it is the key in a key-value pair, so it expects something (a value) after it (or assumes `nil` if nothing follows, often in method definitions using keyword arguments like your example). A typical use might be `model_instance.update(id: 25)` where you are essentially passing in a hash to the `update` method with `id` as the key and `25` as the value. The older way to write this in Ruby is with a "hash rocket" like so: `model_instance.update(:id => 25)`.
More reading on Ruby hashes: https://www.rubyguides.com/2020/05/ruby-hash-methods
More reading on keyword arguments: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/06/rubys-method-arguments

Now if you're paying attention that hash rocket now uses the 3rd type you're asking about. When you see a colon preceding a string like that it is called a "symbol" and it will take some time to get used to them but they are essentially strings in Ruby that are one character fewer to define (and immutable). Instead of using `'id'` or `"id"` as a string, Ruby folks often like to use `:id` as a symbol and it will typically auto-convert to a string when needed. A good example might be an enumerator of sorts.

```
state = :ready
if state == :ready
  state = :finished
else
  state = :undefined
end
```

More reading on Ruby symbols: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/02/ruby-symbols

Comment: Okay so by defining id:, in the resolve method we are passing through an object with the key "id" and the value automatically signed to the ":id" argument, and then when passing through the value of the object to the find method I want to extract that value by using the key "id" rather than passing through the object in a key value pair like the arguments to the update method?

Comment: You have essentially understood it correctly. You should read up more on keyword arguments, but yes, that is how they are used (and essentially how they work).

Comment: You my friend are a legend, and those docs you shared are fantastic. This had been one of my least understood elements as I didn't understand how something could have 3 different names. You have made my life a whole lot easier, thankyou!